# How C++ handles recursive class definitions?

Tags: c++, memory-management, metaprogramming, compiler-optimization, compile-time

I have recently been getting into template metaprogramming with C++ and have been trying to convert some basic functions to their respective recursive compile-time template definition.

For example:

```
template <typename T, T A, unsigned int N>
class pow { enum : T { value = A * pow<T, A, N-1>::value } };
template <typename T, T A> class pow<T, A, 0> { enum : T { value = 1 } };
```

The syntax and the power of templates amazes me. However, one question is bugging me:
**How does C++ handle those recursive definitions? (Resource-wise)**

Or more specifically:

- How does the compiler handle the instance creation of the template classes containing the enum values (where/how is the memory allocated)?
- Do all the classes generated remain in memory after the compilation or are they optimized out by the compiler keeping only the top class (cleanup)?
- Is there a maximum recursive depth which is RAM independent (limitations posed by the compiler itself)?

An in-depth explanation regarding standard compilation of such structures would be highly appreciated.

Comment: _"Is there a maximum recursive depth which..."_: g++ has `-ftemplate-depth=n` see: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options

Comment: It's currenrly 1024 then. But is it a compiler constraint or just a convention (since 17 is a weird pick for previous C++ standards)?

Comment: I cannot imagine a compiler dumping the instantiated types, after all it has no way of knowing whether it's going to be used again some time in the future. It's only during the link phase that sort of culling is performed. And with meta programming I would expect that culling to be complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pow::value` is a constant expression in compile time. The compiler will calculate  `pow<T, A, N>::value` by calculating `A * pow<T, A, N - 1>::value`. The literal `A` is also a const value in compile time, and the compiler would continue to calculate `pow<T, A, N - 1>::value`

...

calculate `pow<T, A, N - n>::value`

calculate `pow<T, A, N - n - 1>::value`

...

Until it stops when it finds no need to calculate `pow<T, A, 1>::value`, since the program had already defined the value of the case where N = 1 as `pow<T, A, 1>::value = 1`

If one would write:

```
int main() {
    int value = pow<int, 1, -1>::value;
}
```

GCC would alert

```
fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of xxx
```

That is because the compiler could't find a constant value to resolve before reaching the maximum recursive depth.

After compilation, the compiler would only retain the value of `pow<T, A, N - n>::value` as an `immediate number` while it won't store any intermediate values resolved during compilation.

```
int main() {
  400546:       55                      push   %rbp
  400547:       48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  ...
    int a = pow<int, 2, 8>::value;
  40055d:       c7 45 f0 00 01 00 00    movl   $0x100,-0x10(%rbp)
  ...
}
```

Here, `$0x100` is the result of `pow<int, 2, 8>::value`. There is no extra address holding this result.

The maximum of recursive depth is specified by the compiler. The default maximum is 900. One could set this value by using the `-ftemplate-depth` switch in GCC.

However, `-ftemplate-depth` value could not exceed the maximum value of a 32-bit integer.

In the example above, the recursion depth is also possibly limited by `type T`.

```
int main() {
    int result = pow<int, 2, 200>::value;
}
```

GCC would alert

```
error: overflow in constant expression [-fpermissive]
```